# Is this the correct usage of React Components?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I want to share my components files with you. The code is syntactically correct and executes just fine. I just want to know, if its logically correct and the correct use of concepts such as states.

Is it correct to save lng and lat coords from the GeoLocation API to the MapContainer State?

Is it the correct use of ComponentDidMount() function.

What other ways can I improve the code.

```js
// Map.js
import React from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';


function Map(props) {
    const screenHeight = window.screen.height;
    return (
        <div style={{ height: screenHeight - 250 }}>
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "123mykey" }}
                center={props.center}
                defaultZoom={props.zoom}
            ></GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
}

Map.defaultProps = {
    center: {
        lat: 59.95,
        lng: 30.33
    },
    zoom: 11
};

export default Map
```

```js
// MapContainer.js
import React from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Map from './Map'

class MapContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            center: {
                lat: 0, lng: 0
            }
        }

        this.getLocation = this.getLocation.bind(this);
        this.showPosition = this.showPosition.bind(this);
    }

    getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }

    showPosition(position) {
        this.setState({
            center: {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            }
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getLocation();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-9">
                    <Map center={this.state.center} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3 d-sm-none d-md-block d-none d-sm-block">
                    <h1>Menu</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MapContainer
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. You only need to import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; in your main index.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems good, you are doing right

> Is it correct to save lng and lat coords from the GeoLocation API to the MapContainer State?
>
> Is it the correct use of ComponentDidMount() function?

Yeah, Why not ?

> What other ways can I improve the code.

there are some minor changes like:

1- you can import `Component` on top and the class definition would be smaller

2- it is a good practice to use arrow function component definition like this

```
export default (props) => {
    const screenHeight = window.screen.height;
    return (
        <div style={{ height: screenHeight - 250 }}>
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "AIzaSyCV1fQD2VC6HoNbuuSPkE0q_QZvDf117PY" }}
                center={props.center}
                defaultZoom={props.zoom}
            ></GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
}
```

generally you are using react in right way, keep going

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine at `MapContainer` (Example 2) but I propose separate your view based logics and the others. For example, the `getLocation` function is not based on your view (not depending React component or changing the view) so we can plug out this logic function into an independent function later the `showPosition` function is going to use that function.